# Is it possible to import a type and assign it an alias in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have two exported functions with the same name (`reducer`) in two different files

I can import them like this:

```
import { * } as appReducer from '../app.reducer';
import { * } as otherReducer from './other.reducer';
```

and access the function as `appReducer.reducer`

If I don't wish to import everything with *, why cant i do:

```
import { reducer } as appReducer from './app.reducer';
```

Possible some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
import { reducer as appReducer } from './app.reducer';
```

As shown in the [docs about importing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import).